# Replace video tags from HTML string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.2

The HTML string is:

```
"<div>\r\n<video controls=\"controls\" height=\"313\" id=\"video201643154436\" poster=\"/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/18/content_56883622_18f242e114.jpg\" width=\"500\"><source src=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />\r\nPlease download the file: <a href=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4\">video/mp4</a></video>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div>test description</div>\r\n\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<video controls=\"controls\" height=\"300\" id=\"video201644152011\" poster=\"\" width=\"400\"><source src=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />\r\nPlease download the file: <a href=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4\">video/mp4</a></video>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n</div>\r\n"
```

I want to replace all video tags including its content and sub tags with `[[ Video ]]`

The expected output is:

```
"<div>\r\n[[ Video ]]\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div>test description</div>\r\n\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n[[ Video ]]\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n</div>\r\n"
```

I have tried using the regex `/<video\s(.*?)<\/video(?=[>])>/`, but it's not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to substitute this two exact strings, and also the content inside this tags

first the beginning and ending strings:

```
"<video "

"</video>"

puts html_text.gsub("<video ","[[ video ]] ").gsub('</video>',"[[ video ]]")
```

This should work

```
irb(main):020:0> <div>
[[ video ]]  controls="controls" height="313" id="video201643154436" poster="/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/18/content_56883622_18f242e114.jpg" width="500"><source src="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />
Please download the file: <a href="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4">video/mp4</a>[[ video ]]
</div>

<div>test description</div>

<div>
<div>
[[ video ]]  controls="controls" height="300" id="video201644152011" poster="" width="400"><source src="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />
Please download the file: <a href="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4">video/mp4</a>[[ video ]]
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
=> true
```

or with regular expressions

```
puts html_text.gsub(/<\/?video[\s>]/, "[[ video ]]")

<div>
[[ video ]]controls="controls" height="313" id="video201643154436" poster="/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/18/content_56883622_18f242e114.jpg" width="500"><source src="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />
Please download the file: <a href="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4">video/mp4</a>[[ video ]]
</div>

<div>test description</div>

<div>
<div>
[[ video ]]controls="controls" height="300" id="video201644152011" poster="" width="400"><source src="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />
Please download the file: <a href="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4">video/mp4</a>[[ video ]]
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Finally to remove all the inside this tag and all the content replace all. the problem is the \n character use this modifiers:

> ```
> /.*/m         multiline: . matches newline
> /.*/i         ignore case
> /.*/x         extended: ignore whitespace in pattern
> ```

so finally if we join alltogether the regular expression is:

```
puts html_text.gsub(/<video\s.*?<\/video>/mix, "[[ video ]]")
```

result

```
irb(main):043:0> <div>
[[ video ]]
</div>

<div>test description</div>

<div>
<div>
[[ video ]]
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
=> true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is not what want. I want to remove   `controls="controls" height="313" id="video201643154436" poster="/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/18/content_56883622_18f242e114.jpg" width="500"><source src="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br /> Please download the file: <a href="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4">video/mp4</a>` also

Comment: I add the solution for the final doubt, finally I get the point @rahul

Answer (score 0):

Parsing html with regex very hard task to do. I'll suggest to use `nokogiri` or similar gem to parse it to ast and replace nodes you need.

Answer (score 0):

anquegi's solution works perfectly. In the meantime, I tried nokogiri:

```
str = "<div>\r\n<video controls=\"controls\" height=\"313\" id=\"video201643154436\" poster=\"/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/18/content_56883622_18f242e114.jpg\" width=\"500\"><source src=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />\r\nPlease download the file: <a href=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/23/newtons_law.mp4\">video/mp4</a></video>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div>test description</div>\r\n\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<video controls=\"controls\" height=\"300\" id=\"video201644152011\" poster=\"\" width=\"400\"><source src=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support video.<br />\r\nPlease download the file: <a href=\"/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/24/test.mp4\">video/mp4</a></video>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n</div>\r\n"

doc =  Nokogiri::HTML(str)

doc.css("video").each do |video|
  new_node = doc.create_element "p"
  new_node.inner_html = "[[ Video ]]"
  video.replace new_node
end

new_str = doc.css("body").to_s
```